# How to databind from a data template in DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a DataGrid with the following setup:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="AperturesDataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Snapshots, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource ContentDataGridCentering}"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="True"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    RowHeight="24"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Width="*"
                            CanUserSort="True"
                            SortMemberPath="Name"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                            Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Width="*"
                            CanUserSort="True"
                            SortMemberPath="Name"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions"
                                Width="100"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="RoomNameGrid"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <btn:DropDownButton
                                    MainImage="/Pollination.Core;Component/Resources/16x16/export.png"
                                    HoverImage="/Pollination.Core;Component/Resources/16x16/exportHover.png"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Cursor="Hand"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Height="15"
                                    Margin="5,0,1,0"
                                    ToolTip="">
                                <btn:DropDownButton.Menu>
                                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding ExportHb}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                                  Header='Honeybee Model *.hbjson'/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </btn:DropDownButton.Menu>
                            </btn:DropDownButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How do I bind the MenuItem to a Command that exists as the DataContext.ExportHb on the Window, and then pass the underlying object of the DataGridRow as the parameter? I am getting Binding Expression errors now.

```
BindingExpression path error: 'ExportHb' property not found on 'object' ''SnapshotWrapper' (HashCode=-1805182346)'. BindingExpression:Path=ExportHb; DataItem='SnapshotWrapper' (HashCode=-1805182346); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

SnapshotWrapper is the object that each row is bound to. Any help would be appreciated. I obviously tried the relative source binding and binding to element name but that didn't work.

Comment: You should show us the declaration of the ExportHb property. As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. The Binding is inherently OneWay (because the DataGrid never sets its ItemsSource property), and UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay and OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: You can't reach any DataContext ourside the ContextMenu. You can use a routed command with the MenuItem. Then handle it on a parent e.g. Window and delegate the execute handler to the DataContext.ExportHb

Comment: @BionicCode how would I do that? Any examples would be appreciated. Just as a note. How come I can route a menu item command from a context menu on a data grid row but can't do it when it's a menu item on a button?

Comment: @Clemens ExportHb is just a RelayCommand handled inside of the Window.DataContext aka. ViewModel. I am using an MVVM pattern here and MVVM Light libs to handle commands.

Comment: The error message is clear, there is no ExportHb property in class SnapshotWrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routed events and relative bindings are resolved by different engines and they traverse the element tree differently.

Routed events (which includes routed commands, as they are technically routed events) are controlled by the dependency property system and traverse a composite tree that is a hybrid of the visual and logical tree. This allows the event to route between disconnected visual trees. For example, a click raised inside a `Popup` or `ContextMenu` can be handled on a logical parent e.g., the element tree's root like a `Window`.

The binding engine traverses the visual tree in order to find an ancestor data source. In the case of the `ContextMenu` or the `Popup` the visual tree of those elements is disconnected from the main visual tree. A `ContextMenu` is always hosted inside a `Popup`, hence they share the same behavior. That is that the content of a `Popup.Child` is hosted in its own `Window` instance. A `Window` always creates its own visual tree. Still that `Window` is logically connected to the element that owns it. The binding engine will not bridge that two individual visual trees the dependency property engine is doing.

The solution to your problem is to use routed commands or routed events to trigger a parent element to execute the menu item's command action.

Another solution could be to implement the `ICommand` on the data item, so that the `DataGridColumn` can bind to it (as the data item is the only available data context in your case, which is inherited by the `ContextMenu`). However, if the command action does not operate on the particular data item or requires the parent view model to execute the command action, then implementing the `ICommand` on those data items can be considered bad class design.

Because you pass the data item as command parameter to the command chances are high that the command operates within the scope of the data item. If the command implementation does not require a reference to the parent view model class to execute, you should prefer to implement the `ICommand` in the data item instead of using routed commands. In this case, the `MenuItem` could directly bind to the `ICommand` that is now defined by the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` (the row's data item).

Because implementing the `ICommand` on the data item is self-explanatory and only feasible in special use cases and you were not talking about what the command is doing I will give an example on the general approach that depends on routed commands and that can always be used.

An advantage of routed commands is that you can associate them with keyboard shortcuts or mouse gestures.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <btn:DropDownButton>
    <btn:DropDownButton.Menu>
  
      <!-- 
           The DataContext is automatically inherited from the parent owner.
           In case of your example, the DataContext is the row data item itself.  
      -->
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="{x:Static MainWindow.ExportHbCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                  Header='Honeybee Model *.hbjson' />
      </ContextMenu>
    </btn:DropDownButton.Menu>
  </btn:DropDownButton>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
Based on the context, the example assumes that `ExportHb` is the `ICommand` exposed by your view model (because the property name does not indicate that it returns an `ICommand`, for example `ExportHbCommand` - instead the grammar indicates a method).

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedUICommand ExportHbCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Export Hb model",
    nameof(MainWindow.ExportHbCommand),
    typeof(MainWindow));

  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;

    // Register the command handlers.
    // Alternatively, use XAML to register them.  

    var exportHbCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.ExportHbCommand, 
      ExecutedExportHbCommand, 
      CanExecuteExportHbCommand);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(exportHbCommandBinding);  
  }

  private void CanExecuteExportHbCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = this.MainViewModel.ExportHb.CanExecute(e.CommandParameter);
   
  private void ExecutedExportHbCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.MainViewModel.ExportHb.Execute(e.CommandParameter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great example and an explanation. This works and makes sense to me now.